# Groovy httpbuilder ResponseParseException Invalid JSON string

Tags: php, json, grails, groovy, httpbuilder

i trying to build a api consumer in groovy using httpBuilder. My backend api returns json output with content type application/json. But when i set  content type in httpbuilder object to JSON it throws Invalid Json String error.

```
static def webServiceRequest(String baseUrl, String path, def data,method=Method.GET,contentType=ContentType.JSON){
        try {
            def ret = null
            def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
            http.request(method, contentType) {
                uri.path = path
                if(method==Method.GET)
                    uri.query = data
                else
                    body = data
                headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'


                response.success = { resp, json ->
                    println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
                    ret = json
                    println '--------------------'
                }
            }
            return ret

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the above function calls the api.

```
def response = webServiceRequest(grailsApplication.config.getProperty ("site.triggerReasons"),'/do/dataquality/FOSAutomation/doAction/',data,Method.GET,ContentType.JSON)
```

actual output on browser with content type application/json

```
{ "status" : "OK", "data" : { "totalTasks" : 0 }, "error" : "" }
```

exception stacktrace:

```
groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: OK
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:467)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:417)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:366)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$request.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.nnacres.ApiConsumer.webServiceRequest(ApiConsumer.groovy:29)
    at com.nnacres.ApiConsumer$webServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.AllocatorService$$EQ8pAKDw.clearTasksService(AllocatorService.groovy:114)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.AllocatorService$$DQ8pAKDw.clearTasksService(Unknown Source)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.AllocatorService.clearTasksService(AllocatorService.groovy)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.AllocatorService$clearTasksService$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.AllocatorService$clearTasksService$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.nnacres.taskAllocator.RiAllocatorController.clearTasks(RiAllocatorController.groovy:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:50)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1461)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(Endpo
intWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:143)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
    at net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper.parseText(JsonSlurper.java:80)
    at groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry.parseJSON(ParserRegistry.java:248)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.parseResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:518)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:460)
    ... 74 more
```

the issue is coming when the service i'm hitting is in PHP.
In PHP service i'm setting content type application/json using **header('Content-Type: application/json');**. and then just echo the result in a controller.

Comment: add `response.failure = { resp -> println resp.statusLine }` and see what it outputs

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-jenkins-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/jenkins/JiraRestService.groovy#L147  def result=JSON.parse(json.toString())

Comment: your php server obviously doesn't return 200 `statusCode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the version of groovy-httpbuilder jar. I was using old version (0.5.0-RC2).

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.5.0-RC2'
```

now i changed that to latest 0.7.1

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.7.1'
```

now its working fine.